# Преобразование строки в UTF-8

Tags: ruby, кодировка

Считываю почту из ящика с помощью гема "mail". Возникает затык при считывании тела письма:

```
mail.body.decoded
```

Падает с ошибкой:

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
```

Добавляю:

```
mail.body.decoded.force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

Получаю:

```
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

Можно ли каким-то образом вырезать с этой строки ни читаемые символы и/или как то преобразовать ее в UTF-8?
Таким образом работает, но весь текст заменяется вопросами (?):

```
 mail.body.decoded.encode("UTF-16be", :invalid => :replace, :replace => "?").encode('UTF-8')
```

Хотелось бы удалить только не читаемые символы.

UPDATE
Кодировка письма при этом UTF-8:

```
{"charset"=>"utf-8", "format"=>"fixed"}
{"charset"=>"utf-8"}
```

UPDATE2
mail.body.decoded.bytes:

```
228
207
194
210
217
202
32
196
197
206
216
46
13
10
13
10
13
10
243
208
193
211
201
194
207
46
32
238
197
212
44
32
206
197
32
203
210
201
212
201
222
206
207
46
32
235
193
203
32
212
207
204
216
203
207
32
196
207
208
201
219
213
32
207
212
208
210
193
215
203
213
32
45
32
211
207
207
194
221
213
46
13
10
13
10
13
10
13
10
13
10
```

Comment: вы знаете в какой кодировке тело письма?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman конкретно данное письмо это мультипарт, кодировки такие, точнее content_type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=fixed, text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: Возможно, указанная кодировка не совпадает с реальной. Хотя-я... `mail.body.decoded.encoding` что показывает?

Comment: @D-side показывает это: ASCII-8BIT

Comment: @S.Ivanov тогда похоже, что там и правда не UTF-8. Но сказать наверняка смогу только имея `mail.body.decoded.bytes`, если в письме нет ничего секретного :)

Comment: @D-side дополнил вопрос

Comment: `mail.body.decoded.force_encoding('koi8-r').encode("utf-8")` => `"Добрый день.\r\n\r\n\r\nСпасибо. Нет, не критично. Как только допишу отправку - сообщу.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"`. Это KOI8-R. Хедер врёт и руби вполне справедливо жалуется.

Comment: @D-side спасибо, данный вопрос это решает. А не подскажете, может есть что-то универсальное, ну например здесь KOI8-R, а если будет что то другое. Имею в виду, может универсальный способ преобразования любой кодировки с русскими символами в UTF-8?

Comment: @S.Ivanov возможно всё, но у этого решения будет своя [точность](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%91%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%9F%D0%9D%D0%AF) и ограничения. По-хорошему, клиент должен указывать правильную кодировку. Если не указывает -- его проблемы.

Comment: @D-side, а еще такой момент, возможно ли как-то проверять, какая кодировка приходит? Например, те письма, которые пришли в изначально верной кодировке UTF8 после обработки .force_encoding('koi8-r').encode("utf-8") на выходе получается KOI8R: -------- п÷п╣я─п╣п╫п╟п©я

Comment: @S.Ivanov ещё раз, кодировка должна быть указана в заголовке письма. Письмо, которое вы привели в вопросе, кривое (утверждает, что оно в UTF-8, но реально KOI8-R) и корректная работа с ним ничем не гарантируется, стоит посоветовать отправителю сменить или донастроить клиент.